# Maintainable Web Widgets

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, widget

How do you create maintainable web widgets?

Right now, I allow my web users to create web widgets via a simple interface, and all the javascript, css, and html needed for that widget gets saved in a database table cell, which is very unmaintainable.

Is there are better way of allowing people to create widgets, yet make them maintainable by the website admin?

Comment: Maybe you should expand a little on what exactly you mean by "web widget".

Comment: If you go to igoogle, you will see a screen full of widgets, and you can add, remove and move the widgets to your hearts content. I have a similar site with widgets, but each time I create a widget or a user creates a widget which gets saved to a database, it makes it very unmaintainable when trying to find a fault with any one of the created widgets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an official W3C draft for Web Widgets at

- http://www.w3.org/TR/widgets/

> This specification standardizes a packaging format for software known as widgets. Widgets are client-side applications that are authored using Web standards, but whose content can also be embedded into Web documents. The specification relies on PKWare's Zip specification as the archive format, XML as a configuration document format, and a series of steps that runtimes follow when processing and verifying various aspects of a package.

You might also be interested in other vendor's widget implementations as given at

- http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget

The widgets on Google's iGoogle are called Gadgets. There are API docs available for them:

- http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/gadgets/ and
- http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/igoogle/

Comment: I was more thinking about the twitter type widgets over at: http://twitter.com/goodies/widget_search

Comment: @oshirowanen well, maybe you should decide which type of widgets you mean first. In the comments below the question you refered to iGoogle. But regardless of which you mean, the links above should give you many ideas on how to come up with maintainable web widgets.

Answer (score 0):

W3C Widgets is also used for Web Widgets - see [Apache Wookie](http://incubator.apache.org/wookie/) for an example.